# update the weekday when the date changes

Tags: flutter, date, dart, for-loop, weekday

I'm writing a calendar app. I want to show the weekday of a specific date. I've got a for loop which iterates the day of the date each time it goes through the loop.
So the date changes each time.
The goal is to update the weekday when the date changes and save it in a list. But it doesn't work as I expect it. The weekday stays the same value each time the loop is passed.

```
var wochenTag = DateTime(
DateTime.now().year,
DateTime.now().month,);
```

the for loop:

```
List<String> listeWeekday() {
  List<String> gesamteWeekdays = [];
  for (int d = 1; d <= dateMonth; d++) {
    wochenTag.format('yyyy-MM-$d');
    gesamteWeekdays.add(
      wochenTag.weekday.toString(),
    );
  }
  return gesamteWeekdays;
}
```

I tried a few things, which didn't work. Does anyone get a solution or a better way?
Thank your for your help.

Best regards
Patrick

Comment: `format` is not defined for `DateTime`. Are you using an extension method?

Comment: I loaded the intl.dart package in my pubspec.yaml so that format can be used with DateTime

Comment: I think the `format` method has no side effect. In other words it returns the date formatted. Can you check that?

Comment: Sorry for my question, but how do I check that?

Comment: type `String date = wochenTag.format('yyyy-MM-$d');` if it does not throw an error it is a string.

Comment: there are no errors. wochenTag still got den type DateTime

Comment: Change `gesamteWeekdays.add(date);` does it get the result you want?